# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null laravel and using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I already search for this problem and still doesn't work for me, I wanna make a insert my image to the database using laravel and jquery, but when I try my code is error, and I search for my problem is still doesn't have any clue and my code still error, anyone can help me to make my problem stop? This is the first time I use inserting images into a database in laravel using jquery too.

this is code for view :

```
<form name="formPayment" action="javascript:;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Select Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="show-image" class="form-control-file" id="showImg">
                <div class="image-container">
                     <img id="proof_image" src="#" alt="Proof Image">                                        
                </div>
                <div class="text-danger" id="error_show_img"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

jquery code :

```
$("#btnPay").on("click", function () {
    var nameImg = $("input[type=file]").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: `my-url/insert-image`,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: {
            fieldImg: nameImg
        },
        success: function (success) {
            console.log(success)
        }
    });
});
```

controller :

```
public function insertImage(Request $request) {
    // get image request input
    $image = $payment->file('fieldImg');
    $name_image = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path().'/image/proof', $name_image);

    return response()->json([
         'a' => $name_image
    ]);
}
```

When I run, the output is error like this :

```
message: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"
```

What I miss on my code? And how to be fix my code? Thank You

Comment: `getClientOriginalName() on null`  add null check before use that function

Comment: what kind of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this code in my jquery and it's work :

```
$("#btnPay").on("click", function () {

     var formData = new FormData()
     var image = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];

     formData.append('fieldImg', image);

     $.ajax({
          url: `my-url/insert-image`,
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function (success) {
               console.log(success)
          }
     });
});
```

And for the result is:

```
a: "36587e2603892d0923fc577ba1f9b96f.jpg"
```

I dont know it can be stored database or not, but this is solve my problem to check my image name from my controller

Answer (score 2):

you need to send file via ajax

which you can do via `new FormData()`

```js
$("#btnPay").on("click", function () {

    var formData = new FormData()
    var image = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];

    formData.append('fieldImg', image);

    $.ajax({
        url: `my-url/insert-image`,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (success) {
            console.log(success)
        }
    });
});
```

now you can do like

```php
$image = $payment->file('fieldImg');
$name_image = $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Sorry I wanna ask again from result is still error, in my console the error is like this `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`, I must edit again on my jquery or anything else?

Comment: @LuckALip try now

Comment: still same, I don't know what happen

Comment: `console.log(formData)` try this and check

Comment: when I console, the result is like this `FormData {}`, the append is not work?